# How can I create slugify in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, slug

I have started to use symfony2 and I have found some functions that exists in symfony 1.4 like slugify. I need this in order to improve the furl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use either l3ppard's [sluggable extension](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md)  ( GitHub [repository](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions)) ...

... or KnpLabs [sluggable behavior](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#sluggable) ( GitHub [repository](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors) ).

Comment: thanks a lot nifr. I'll try them. I have also see [stof](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst). Witch do you think is the best option

Comment: StofDoctrineExtensions provides easier integration ( registering services, setting up the listeners ) in symfony2 but not the extensions themselves.

Comment: Late to the game but a non unique slug is next to useless for most use cases.

Comment: I've found this library - https://github.com/cocur/slugify. Works great.

Answer (score 10):

If you have php-intl :

```
/**
 * Transform (e.g. "Hello World") into a slug (e.g. "hello-world").
 *
 * @param string $string
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function slugify($string)
{
    $rule = 'NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC';
    $transliterator = \Transliterator::create($rule);
    $string = $transliterator->transliterate($string);

    return preg_replace(
        '/[^a-z0-9]/',
        '-',
        strtolower(trim(strip_tags($string)))
    );
}
```

Otherwise, have a look on [the doctrine extensions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html)

Comment: This answer is very simple and seems to work great so far as long as Transliterator is enabled. Thank you.

Comment: not enough people know that transforming a non-ascii input (like french with accents or æ that should be transformed into ae  etc.) into ascii is a problem long solved in a standard way by unicode

Comment: Doctrine extension is using [Behat Transliterator](https://github.com/Behat/Transliterator)

Answer (score 2):

I used [util.php](http://brandonwamboldt.github.io/utilphp/) for slugify. It doesn't require Symfony though, but works well with it.

```
util::slugify('This is a random --string with an Ãccent');
=> Returns 'this-is-a-random-string-with-an-accent'
```